# Draw cyrillic text on node.js gm

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I have code like this

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm('image.jpg')
  .font("Lato-Regular.ttf", 36)
  .fill('#333')
  .drawText(200,40,'Кириллический текст')
  .write('result.jpg', (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });
```

But resulting text is

[image: wrong encoded text on image]

How to get it work correctly? code was running on windows 10, but I don't that the reason is it.

Comment: Well, I have to run it on Ubuntu, where all cyrillic text is OK. So, the problem is operation system. But I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add `.encoding('Unicode')` somewhere before `.write`.